# Show that $\iint_C \nabla \boldsymbol{G} \cdot \boldsymbol{\hat{N}}dS = 0 $

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $C_1$ be the cylinder wall given by 
$$C_1=\{ (x,y,z)\ |\ x^2+y^2=1,z\geq 0,z\leq 1 \}$$
and $C_2$ the top of the cylinder, given by
$$C_2=\{(x,y,z)\ |\ x^2+y^2 \leq 1,z=1\}$$
Let $C\ =\ C_1 \cup C_2$ the "bottomless" cylinder, with the normal vector pointing outwards. Furthermore there is a given vectorfield, in terms of cylindercoordinates $\boldsymbol{\hat{r}}$, $\boldsymbol{\hat{\theta}}$, $\boldsymbol{\hat{k}}$ given by:
$$\boldsymbol{G}(r,\theta)=g(r,\theta)\boldsymbol{\hat{r}}+0\cdot \boldsymbol{\hat{\theta}}+0\cdot \boldsymbol{\hat{k}}=g(r,\theta)\boldsymbol{\hat{r}}.$$
Assume $g(r,\theta)$ is continuously differentiable. Show that $$\iint_C \nabla \boldsymbol{G} \cdot \boldsymbol{\hat{N}}dS = 0 $$ by direct integration.
In cylindercoordinates I can use 
$$\nabla \boldsymbol{G} = -\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial g}{\partial \theta}\boldsymbol{\hat{k}}.$$
I've tried calculating the total integral as a sum of the integral of the cylinder wall and the integral of the top of the cylinder. I've found the integral on the wall to be 0 since $\boldsymbol{\hat{N}}\cdot \boldsymbol{\hat{k}}=\boldsymbol{\hat{r}} \cdot \boldsymbol{\hat{k}}=0$ but I dont see how the other integral will become zero (which is supposed to be so if the total integral is to be 0)? I know I can prove the total integral by using Stokes theorem but I would like to do it this way.